# Can i pause and close blender and then resume it later?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So i got an intro from youtube.It looks really cool but the rendering takes 5-6 maybe 7 hours for just 10 seconds :(
Is there a way i can pause it and then resume the render ANY time i want?
Please say yes :D

Comment: Render as an image sequence, not as video, and compile later. In the output section disable the  **Overwrite** option. That way you can resume rendering and not loose any of the already rendered files.